# Adjusting coefficients of a LP and HP filter for a new sampling rate

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I am pretty new to DSP and try to undertand some concepts and the relations between them.

I currently learning about the Pan-Tompkins algorithm and trying to recreate it in Matlab ([Pan–Tompkins algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%E2%80%93Tompkins_algorithm)). The sampling rate for this algorithm was 200Hz but I am working with data sampled in 512Hz. 
The coefficients for the filters are:

```
LP:
b = [1 0 0 0 0 0 -2 0 0 0 0 0 1];
a = [1 -2 1];

HP:
b = [-1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];
a = [1 1];
```

my question is: how do I adjust those coefficients for a new sampling rate?

p.s: I can't work with any of the Matlab's toolkits.

Comment: Can you work with Octave? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45840-complete-pan-tompkins-implementation-ecg-qrs-detector

Comment: hey, no. It has to be done in Matlab. I have seen this implementation of the algorithm but of course I don't want to copy it and therefore trying to understand the basics behind it.